# Flatten assorted array using ramda

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming, ramda.js

I have the following data structure which contains `Date` objects, some of which are nested inside objects:

```
[
  new Date("2018-11-20T09:00:00.000Z"),
  new Date("2018-11-19T09:00:00.000Z"),
  {
    "before": new Date("2018-12-14T00:00:00.000Z")
  }
]
```

Using ramda, I’d like to flatten it so that it becomes:

```
[
  new Date("2018-11-20T09:00:00.000Z"),
  new Date("2018-11-19T09:00:00.000Z"),
  new Date("2018-12-14T00:00:00.000Z")
]
```

I’ve tried using a combination of `map`, `values`, `unnest` and `flatten` but with no luck. I would ideally like this to work so that it would flatten regardless of the nested object and key names.

Comment: Do the objects contain other info besides timestamps?

Comment: @BryanDowning They don’t, no.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use R.when with R.has and R.prop to extract the value from objects that has the property inside a map.

```js
const { pipe, map, when, has, prop } = R;

const extractOrVal = (p) => map(when(has(p), prop(p)));

const extractOrValBefore = extractOrVal('before');

const data = [
  new Date("2018-11-20T09:00:00.000Z"),
  new Date("2018-11-19T09:00:00.000Z"),
  {
    "before": new Date("2018-11-14T00:00:00.000Z")
  }
];

console.log(extractOrValBefore(data));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

If there can be multiple keys, or you don't know the name of the keys, you can use R.values. This extracts all values from objects, that are not Date:

```js
const { chain, values, unless, is } = R;

const extractAndFlatten = chain(unless(is(Date), values));

const data = [
  new Date("2018-11-20T09:00:00.000Z"),
  new Date("2018-11-19T09:00:00.000Z"),
  {
    "before": new Date("2018-12-14T00:00:00.000Z")
  }
];

console.log(extractAndFlatten(data));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

And another [suggestion by Scott Christopher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53287651/flatten-assorted-array-using-ramda/53287774?noredirect=1#comment93458995_53287774) to extract unknown/multiple props, and flattening the results:

```js
const { chain, ifElse, is, of, values } = R;

const extractAndFlatten = chain(ifElse(is(Date), of, values));

const data = [
  new Date("2018-11-20T09:00:00.000Z"),
  new Date("2018-11-19T09:00:00.000Z"),
  {
    "before": new Date("2018-12-14T00:00:00.000Z")
  }
];

console.log(extractAndFlatten(data));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I've included runable snippets in the answer, and both work. I'm not sure why you get different results.

Comment: Just double checking things now to see what’s up on my side.

Comment: Could it be that in my console they are `Date` objects? When copying them over to here they appear as strings.

Comment: It seems logical, because dates are object, that don't have the `before` property.

Comment: I have just updated the question for clarity (wasn’t aware copying from Chrome console parses `Date` objects into strings).

Comment: Nice answer. Minor suggestion that `when(complement(f))` in your second example can also be represented as `unless(f)`. Another option for your second example would be `chain(ifElse(is(Date), of, values))`.

Comment: @ScottChristopher - thanks a lot! Both great suggestions which I've added to answer.

Answer (score 1):

https://ramdajs.com/docs/#map

Here's a [repl](https://ramdajs.com/repl/#?let%20arr%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%222018-11-20T09%3A00%3A00.000Z%22%2C%0A%20%20%222018-11-19T09%3A00%3A00.000Z%22%2C%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22before%22%3A%20%222018-11-14T00%3A00%3A00.000Z%22%0A%20%20%7D%0A%5D%3B%0A%0AR.map%28%28item%29%20%3D%3E%20item.before%20%7C%7C%20item%2C%20arr%29%3B), and the code :

```
let arr = [
"2018-11-20T09:00:00.000Z",
"2018-11-19T09:00:00.000Z",
{
  "before": "2018-11-14T00:00:00.000Z"
}
];

R.map((item) => item.before || item, arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want plain Javascript solution.

Assumption - Objects are nested to 1 level as seen in OP

```js
var arr = [
  "2018-11-20T09:00:00.000Z",
  "2018-11-19T09:00:00.000Z",
  {
    "before": "2018-11-14T00:00:00.000Z"
  }
]


var result = arr.map(d => typeof d == "object" ? Object.values(d) : d)


console.log(result.flat())
```